# st9720 LCD SPI communication with ATmega328P

Tags: c, spi, atmega, atmel, lcd

I am currently trying to write a simple string to my LCD which uses a ST9720, when i run the code ive sourced to print a simple string, i get quite a bit of noise on the LCD. Im not sure why, i was thinking perhaps maybe the clock value, but then am very unsure on what it should be set to, to get rid of the noise on the LCD.
The LCD is connected to an atmega328P chip, which is connected to an avr programmer that communicates through spi. This is using atmel as well, i sourced the code from https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki/u8g2as7
It uses the u8g2 library. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <u8g2.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define DISPLAY_CLK_DIR DDRB
#define DISPLAY_CLK_PORT PORTB
#define DISPLAY_CLK_PIN 5

#define DISPLAY_DATA_DIR DDRB
#define DISPLAY_DATA_PORT PORTB
#define DISPLAY_DATA_PIN 3

#define DISPLAY_CS_DIR DDRB
#define DISPLAY_CS_PORT PORTB
#define DISPLAY_CS_PIN 2

//#define DISPLAY_DC_DIR DDRB
//#define DISPLAY_DC_PORT PORTB
//#define DISPLAY_DC_PIN 1

#define DISPLAY_RESET_DIR DDRB
#define DISPLAY_RESET_PORT PORTB
#define DISPLAY_RESET_PIN 0


#define P_CPU_NS (1000000000UL / F_CPU)

u8g2_t u8g2;

uint8_t u8x8_avr_delay(u8x8_t *u8x8, uint8_t msg, uint8_t arg_int, void *arg_ptr)
{
    uint8_t cycles;

    switch(msg)
    {
        case U8X8_MSG_DELAY_NANO:     // delay arg_int * 1 nano second
            // At 20Mhz, each cycle is 50ns, the call itself is slower.
            break;
        case U8X8_MSG_DELAY_100NANO:    // delay arg_int * 100 nano seconds
            // Approximate best case values...
#define CALL_CYCLES 26UL
#define CALC_CYCLES 4UL
#define RETURN_CYCLES 4UL
#define CYCLES_PER_LOOP 4UL

            cycles = (100UL * arg_int) / (P_CPU_NS * CYCLES_PER_LOOP);

            if(cycles > CALL_CYCLES + RETURN_CYCLES + CALC_CYCLES) 
                break;

            __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "1: sbiw %0,1" "\n\t" // 2 cycles
            "brne 1b" : "=w" (cycles) : "0" (cycles) // 2 cycles
            );
            break;
        case U8X8_MSG_DELAY_10MICRO:    // delay arg_int * 10 micro seconds
            for(int i=0 ; i < arg_int ; i++)
                _delay_us(10);
            break;
        case U8X8_MSG_DELAY_MILLI:      // delay arg_int * 1 milli second
            for(int i=0 ; i < arg_int ; i++)
                _delay_ms(1);
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


uint8_t u8x8_avr_gpio_and_delay(u8x8_t *u8x8, uint8_t msg, uint8_t arg_int, void *arg_ptr)
{
    // Re-use library for delays

    switch(msg)
    {
        case U8X8_MSG_GPIO_AND_DELAY_INIT:  // called once during init phase of u8g2/u8x8
            DISPLAY_CLK_DIR |= 1<<DISPLAY_CLK_PIN;
            DISPLAY_DATA_DIR |= 1<<DISPLAY_DATA_PIN;
            DISPLAY_CS_DIR |= 1<<DISPLAY_CS_PIN;
            //DISPLAY_DC_DIR |= 1<<DISPLAY_DC_PIN;
            DISPLAY_RESET_DIR |= 1<<DISPLAY_RESET_PIN;
            break;              // can be used to setup pins
        case U8X8_MSG_GPIO_SPI_CLOCK:        // Clock pin: Output level in arg_int
            if(arg_int)
                DISPLAY_CLK_PORT |= (1<<DISPLAY_CLK_PIN);
            else
                DISPLAY_CLK_PORT &= ~(1<<DISPLAY_CLK_PIN);
            break;
        case U8X8_MSG_GPIO_SPI_DATA:        // MOSI pin: Output level in arg_int
            if(arg_int)
                DISPLAY_DATA_PORT |= (1<<DISPLAY_DATA_PIN);
            else
                DISPLAY_DATA_PORT &= ~(1<<DISPLAY_DATA_PIN);
            break;
        case U8X8_MSG_GPIO_CS:        // CS (chip select) pin: Output level in arg_int
            if(arg_int)
                DISPLAY_CS_PORT |= (1<<DISPLAY_CS_PIN);
            else
                DISPLAY_CS_PORT &= ~(1<<DISPLAY_CS_PIN);
            break;
        //case U8X8_MSG_GPIO_DC:        // DC (data/cmd, A0, register select) pin: Output level in arg_int
        //  if(arg_int)
        //      DISPLAY_DC_PORT |= (1<<DISPLAY_DC_PIN);
        //  else
        //      DISPLAY_DC_PORT &= ~(1<<DISPLAY_DC_PIN);
        //  break;
        
        case U8X8_MSG_GPIO_RESET:     // Reset pin: Output level in arg_int
            if(arg_int)
                DISPLAY_RESET_PORT |= (1<<DISPLAY_RESET_PIN);
            else
                DISPLAY_RESET_PORT &= ~(1<<DISPLAY_RESET_PIN);
            break;
        default:
            if (u8x8_avr_delay(u8x8, msg, arg_int, arg_ptr))    // check for any delay msgs
                return 1;
            u8x8_SetGPIOResult(u8x8, 1);      // default return value
            break;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    /*
        Select a setup procedure for your display from here: https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki/u8g2setupc
        1. Arg: Address of an empty u8g2 structure
        2. Arg: Usually U8G2_R0, others are listed here: https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki/u8g2reference#carduino-example
        3. Arg: Protocol procedure (u8g2-byte), list is here: https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki/Porting-to-new-MCU-platform#communication-callback-eg-u8x8_byte_hw_i2c
        4. Arg: Defined in this code itself (see above)
    */
    u8g2_Setup_st7920_s_128x64_1(&u8g2, U8G2_R0, u8x8_byte_4wire_sw_spi, u8x8_avr_gpio_and_delay);
    u8g2_InitDisplay(&u8g2);
    u8g2_SetPowerSave(&u8g2, 0);
    
    /* full buffer example, setup procedure ends in _f */
    u8g2_ClearBuffer(&u8g2);
    u8g2_SetFont(&u8g2, u8g2_font_ncenB14_tr);
    u8g2_DrawStr(&u8g2, 1, 18, "U8g2 on AVR");
    u8g2_SendBuffer(&u8g2);
        
    while(1){
    }
}
```

Comment: What baudrate are you using and how much data do you need to send? What makes you think it's a software problem?

Comment: @Lundin using a baud rate of 9600, we dont need to send much data just a string at this point. I am not entirely sure if it is a software problem, just one of the first things i thought it could be as it is printing some of the word, and the rest of screen is noise

Comment: @Lundin currently i have connected the following on the hardware front, on the LCD we have CLK_dir connected to the enable pin on the LCD. Data_dir connected to RW, cs_dir connected to CS, reset_dir connected to RST. but have commented out the DC_dir pin as unsure if this is needed and what pin on the LCD it should be connected to

Comment: That doesn't say anything to me. There are as many standards for LCDs as there are parts on the market, pretty much. If you wish to trouble-shoot the hardware you need to post a schematic at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use `u8g2_Setup_st7920_s_128x64_f()` instead of using `u8g2_Setup_st7920_s_128x64_1()`.